# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len() on assignment of matrix element

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I was having issues with a package using scipy sparse matrices.

As I isolated the problem, I saw that the error is raised when I simply assign an element to a csr or csc matrix.

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
x = csr_matrix(np.eye(10))
x[0,3] = int(4)
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-2e1809373207> in <module>
----> 1 x[0,3] = int(4)

~/anaconda2/envs/macrophage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py in __setitem__(self, key, x)
     67             if x.size != 1:
     68                 raise ValueError('Trying to assign a sequence to an item')
---> 69             self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
     70             return
     71 

~/anaconda2/envs/macrophage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _set_intXint(self, row, col, x)
    795     def _set_intXint(self, row, col, x):
    796         i, j = self._swap((row, col))
--> 797         self._set_many(i, j, x)
    798 
    799     def _set_arrayXarray(self, row, col, x):

~/anaconda2/envs/macrophage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anndata/h5py/h5sparse.py in _set_many(self, i, j, x)
    176     i, j, M, N = self._prepare_indices(i, j)
    177 
--> 178     n_samples = len(x)
    179     offsets = np.empty(n_samples, dtype=self.indices.dtype)
    180     ret = _sparsetools.csr_sample_offsets(M, N, self.indptr, self.indices,

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

It seems that the _set_many() function is expecting multiple values, while **setitem**() expects only one! 
How I can correct this bug?

For reference, I am using scipy 1.3.0.

Thanks.

Comment: As an aside, `int(4)` is redundant; that's just the same as `4`.

Answer (score 0):

With just `scipy.sparse`, your code sample works:

```
In [246]: x=sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(10))                                                              
In [247]: x[0,3]=int(4)                                                                                
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:69: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
In [248]: x                                                                                            
Out[248]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [249]: x.A                                                                                          
Out[249]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

But the traceback

```
~/anaconda2/envs/macrophage/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anndata/h5py/h5sparse.py in _set_many(self, i, j, x)
```

reference another package, https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, which has a `h5py/h5sparse` module.  In some way that's altering the behavior of the standard `sparse` matrix.

The standard `_set_many` (in `scipy.sparse.compressed.py`) first turns `x` into an array, `np.array(x...)`, and uses `nsample = x.size`.

In sum:

- you didn't tell us about the `anndata` package
- the 'bug' appears to be in that package, or your use of it.

Comment: You were right, I didn't notice that the anndata package was overwriting the _set_many function of scipy. I am reporting the problem to the package author, thanks!